# How many Pact Shards can I obtain without moving to the next threat level?

Tags: monster-train

I was wondering if there was a way to tell how many Pact Shards are required to hit the different thresholds.

At the beginning of the game, you start with 0/100:
[image: 0/100]

As you play, you accumulate more and it increases the difficulty to either Grey, Yellow, Orange, or Red.
In this example, [I collected 100 gold and 10 Pact Shards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvVam.png) at the very beginning.

This caused the difficulty to rise to yellow for the first fight:
[image: 1stFight]

After defeating the first boss, my 10/100 went back down to the Grey threat level:
[image]

So it seems that each floor has certain thresholds that once hit, increase the threat level.
**Is there a way to tell how many pact shards I can accumulate without hitting the next threat level?**

Comment: After more research (mostly by the playerbase) it seems the threat level is a description of the difficulty but the actual effect is based on the exact amount of shards. This means there's no point gaming the system to stay out of a specific level.

Comment: @Studoku oh interesting! so more improved units spawn when you have say 110 shards vs when you have 55 while fighting the final boss?

Comment: Exactly. Seraph himself will also have higher stats at 110 than at 55.

Comment: It also means there is no point where you "may as well take shards because they can't make things worse."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no way in game to tell until you have reached the next floor,
however over the past week I've been collecting data, and although I don't have everything yet, I do have what I feel is enough for an answer. I fully intend on adding to this answer in the future.

My data so far: (all from Cov25 runs)
[image: Data May 4, 2021]

The blue colour represents numbers that are not yet final,
for example I do not yet know what the lowest Yellow on Level 6 is at the moment, but it will be either 35 or 40.

So what I do know is:
***On Level 1:***
if you pick up either the +10 (for gold) or +15 (for an artifact), you will go into Yellow,
otherwise the first fight is no threat.

***On Level 2:***
15 Pact Shards you go into Yellow,
30 Pact Shards you go into Orange,
40 Pact Shards you go into Red.

***On Level 3:***
20 Pact Shards you go into Yellow,
35 Pact Shards you go into Orange,
50 Pact Shards you go into Red.

***On Level 4:***
25 Pact Shards you go into Yellow,
45 Pact Shards you go into Orange,
65 Pact Shards you go into Red.

***On Level 5:***
30 Pact Shards you go into Yellow,
55 Pact Shards you go into Orange,
80 Pact Shards you go into Red.

***On Level 6:***
between 35-40 Pact Shards you go into Yellow,
65 Pact Shards you go into Orange,
100 Pact Shards you go into Red.

***On Level 7:***
45 Pact Shards you go into Yellow,
85 Pact Shards you go into Orange,
between 120-125 Pact Shards you go into Red.

***On Level 8: (Final Boss)***
55 Pact Shards you go into Yellow,
115 Pact Shards you go into Orange,
160 Pact Shards you go into Red,
So, you can get between 100 and 110 to keep in yellow and still fight the Last Divinity.

Comment: It's bad form to award a bounty this soon but I honestly can't imagine a better answer.

Comment: @Studoku thank you I appreciate that :) I will be adding more as well once I have more data, just been busy and can't play more at the moment. Going to try and remove any of the blue in the chart.